# How to disconnect and forget Wi-fi Network Programmatically in and above Android API level 29 (>= 29)

Tags: java, android, android-10.0, wifimanager

Trying to disconnect and forget
a WIFI network that was connected via the app using `API level 29 >=` like so:

```java
// Connect to wifi
WifiNetworkSpecifier specifier = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
    .setSsid("my_hotspot")
    .setWpa2Passphrase("secret_password")
    .build();

NetworkRequest request = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
     .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) // we want WiFi
     .setNetworkSpecifier(specifier) // we want _our_ network
     .build();
                
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                
connectivityManager.requestNetwork(request, networkCallback);
```

This works.

But I cant disconnect from this network.
Docs for the deprecated `removeNetwork()` method vaguely mention that I should use `removeNetworkSuggestions` - [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#removeNetwork(int))

But if I try to just remove suggestions I get an error about not having any (which makes sense)
If I try to add my hot spot as a suggestion during connection, it removes succesfully but the process is not disconnecting the device from the hot spot.

Is there any way to achieve disconnection from wifi in post API level 29?

If so how?

NOTE: Would gladly downgrade target apk to API level 28 but since November 2020 Google play accepts only API level 29+  [link](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk)

Comment: I've been struggling with wifi management on android 10+ and the conclusions I've made so far is that it's not possible to connect or disconnect from a specific network programmatically. All the network handling should be done by the user through the UI.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this helps: unregisterNetworkCallback

I use it this way:

```
connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(networkCallback);
```

Docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#unregisterNetworkCallback(android.net.ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback)

I can connect to an access point from within my app and I can disconnect from it again using 'unregisterNetworkCallback'.

However, there is a problem. The AP does not provide an internet connection. That's fine. But after I disconnect from the AP via unregisterNetworkCallback the app wont get back the internet connection. So far I found no way to fix this.

Context: Android app built on Ionic / Angular / Capacitor

Comment: Where should I unregister, onDestory()?

Comment: I too still have a lot of questions. I couldn't fix the problem yet. Not sure what exactly needs to be done to get the internet connection back. So maybe my idea (using connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(networkCallback);) is not helpful.

Comment: It doesn't "Disconnect the wifi" it's still connected